# Zip multiple objects from inputStream in Java

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I have a webapp that allows users to select images and then download them.  For a single image, I use HTML5's anchor download and it works beautifully.  Now I need to allow them to select multiple images, and download them as a .zip file.  I'm using an api to get each image as an InputStream and returning a Jersey Response.

I'm new to zipping and I'm a bit confused with how zipping with InputStream should work.

For **single images**, it works like so:

```
try {
    InputStream imageInputStream = ImageStore.getImage(imageId);

    if (imageInputStream == null) {
        XLog.warnf("Unable to find image [%s].", imageId);
        return Response.status(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_GONE).build();
    }

    Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(imageInputStream);
    response.header("Content-Type", imageType.mimeType());
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "filename=image.jpg");

    return response.build();
}
```

It's not much, but here's the java I have so far for **multiple images**

```
public Response zipAndDownload(List<UUID> imageIds) {
    try {
        // TODO: instantiate zip file?

        for (UUID imageId : imageIds) {
            InputStream imageInputStream = ImageStore.getImage(imageId);
            // TODO: add image to zip file (ZipEntry?)
        }

        // TODO: return zip file
    }
    ...
}
```

I just don't know how to deal with multiple InputStreams, and it seems that I shouldn't have multiple, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `InputStream` per image is ok. To zip the files you need to create a .zip file for them to live in and get a `ZipOutputStream` to write to it:

```
File zipFile = new File("/path/to/your/zipFile.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile)));
```

For each image, create a new `ZipEntry`, add it to the `ZipOutputSteam`, then copy the bytes from your image's `InputStream` to the `ZipOutputStream`:

```
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("PrettyPicture1.jpg");
zos.putNextEntry(ze);
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int count = imageInputStream.read(bytes);
while (count > -1)
{
    zos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    count = imageInputStream.read(bytes);
}
imageInputStream.close();
zos.closeEntry();
```

After you add all the entries, close the `ZipOutputStream`:

```
zos.close();
```

Now your `zipFile` points to a zip file full of pictures you can do whatever you want with. You can return it like you do with a single image:

```
BufferedInputStream zipFileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(zipFileInputStream);
```

But the content type and disposition are different:

```
response.header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=zipFile.zip");
```

Note: You can use the `copy` method from [Guava's `ByteStreams` helper](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to copy the streams instead of copying the bytes manually. Simply replace the `while` loop and the 2 lines before it with this line:

```
ByteStreams.copy(imageInputStream, zos);
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you. For some reason, I was under the impression that multiple InputStreams was bad practice, but in this case, it's very simple. Now to get it to download correctly to the client.

Comment: He shouldn't really need to create the file, just connect the `ZipOutputStream` to the response output stream.

Comment: @EJP, I had a similar problem where I tried your suggestion, and it gave this error `MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream, genericType=class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.`